# ng-persian-datepicker pushes the other elements down upon opening

Tags: html, css, angular, datepicker, persian-calendar

I am using this package ([ng-persian-datepicker](https://github.com/Saeed-Pooyanfar/ng-persian-datepicker)) in my Angular project for converting the Gregorian datepicker to a jalali datepicker.

Problem is, when the datepicker is opened, it pushes all of the other elements down. But I want it to open over the other elements and not push them down.

This is the form before opening the datepicker:

[Image of form before opening datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf99c.png)

This is the form after opening the datepicker:

[Image of form after opening datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H43OX.png)

This is my `html` datepicker input:

```
<div id="dateOfBirth">
      <mat-label
        >{{
          'kyc.personal_information.date_of_birth' | icmLocale
        }}
        (MM/DD/YYYY)</mat-label
      >
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="01/21/1900"
          matInput
          #datepickerInput
          name="dateOfBirth"
          formControlName="dateOfBirth"
          (click)="datepickerInput.open()"
          (focus)="hideError()"
        />
        <ng-persian-datepicker
          [input]="datepickerInput"
          [uiTheme]="'dark'"
          [timeMeridian]="false"
          [timeEnable]="false"
          [dateFormat]="'jYYYY/jM/jD'"
        ></ng-persian-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

I fixed the issue by adding the following `css` code:

```
::ng-deep ng-persian-datepicker .datepicker-outer-container {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        top: 43px;
        right: -10px;
        z-index: 1000;
        background-color: $icm-dark-deep;
      }
```

Comment: to make it easier to get answers, create a simple demo at https://stackblitz.com/, so we can easily view & possibly solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @RPasha. I will do so and update this post.